# Http запрос на авторизацию к Dropbox через Qt

Tags: c++, qt, http, dropbox, dropbox-api

Пытался реализовать доступ к файлам на Dropbox используя Qt. Создал приложение на офф. сайте, создалась папка, но удачно авторизоваться не получается.

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/link/"));
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + QString("тут я вставлял keyApp:тут секрет").toLatin1().toBase64());
replyer = manager->post(request, "link=https://www.dropbox.com/sh/<а тут я вовсе не уверен что нужно было вставлять>?dl=0");
```

Там где линк по идее нужно вставлять ссылку на папку приложения, но её я смог получить только вручную создав доступ по ссылке к той папке. Но даже когда ввел этот адрес возвращали мне ошибку о том, что

> "{\"error\": \"access_denied:unsupported_app_type\"}".

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/auth/token/from_oauth1"));
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer тут acces token который взял на офф. сайта на странице приложения");
replyer = manager->post(request, "{\"oauth1_token\": \"не нашел где брать этот параметр\",\"oauth1_token_secret\": \"не нашел где брать этот параметр"}");
```

Где брать последние два параметра не нашел, в случае запроса с дефолтными возвращает ошибку

> "Error in call to API function \"auth/token/from_oauth1\": Invalid
>   HTTP header \"Authorization\": expecting \"Basic\" auth"

Answer (score 1):

Есть готовая библиотека для работы с Dropbox. Если не хотите её использовать, по крайней мере вы можете посмотреть исходный код, чтобы понять как происходит авторизация там.

https://github.com/b0bh00d/QtDropbox2